# What does it mean for two definitions (of the reals) to be equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I have read that the real numbers can be defined in several ways, but that these definitions are all 'equivalent'. What does this actually mean? Is it that there is a unique set of numbers satisfying each definition, and that these sets are all the same?

Comment: It's not going to be a *unique* set for any definition, but any set satisfying one definition will be *isomorph* in their structure to any set satisfying another definition.

Answer (score 5):

Usually equivalent means, there is an isomorphism between these objects preserving the structure.

No matter which definition of real numbers you choose, it will always be a totally ordered archimedean field verifying, that every nonempty bounded subset has a supremum, which makes the real numbers essentially unique. There are just different ways of constructing such an object.